# UITableView crashing: Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'ShowDetail'

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, tableview, nsexception

Relatively new to iOS development, while look at some older material I've been trying to get my segue to move into my detail view from a table view cell.

Its throwing this error and then crashing in the iOS simulator:

```
2014-03-24 19:47:54.151 Craft Beer[18635:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x109353260 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2014-03-24 19:47:55.016 Craft Beer[18635:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'ShowDetail'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010188f795 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001015f2991 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   UIKit                               0x00000001006f3051 -[UIStoryboardPushSegue destinationContainmentContext] + 0
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000100315768 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1266
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001003158bf -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 221
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010026c712 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 316
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010026c590 _afterCACommitHandler + 460
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010185aff7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010185af67 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010183a6d2 __CFRunLoopRun + 946
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101839f33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001039963a0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000100255043 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    13  Craft Beer                          0x0000000100001fd3 main + 115
    14  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000101f1e5fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException


**"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'ShowDetail'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController."**
```

This seems to be the key, can someone help me rectify this?

Now adding this detail https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc6ZA.png

Comment: Is your tableview inside a navigation controller? Could you put it in one? Otherwise, you'll need a different transition mechanism other than a push segue.

Comment: Looks like you have a push segue from your table view to somewhere else. However your source controller is not hosted by a UINavigationController, hence the error.

Comment: @Krumelur - Does this shed some light? I just created a table view controller and linked it with a new Objective-C Class with inheritance from UITableViewController
http://imgur.com/6N6SsWp,x8i2x9g 
These are some screen shots

Comment: So I solved the issue, very simple. Thanks for the help. Simple as highlighting the table view and embedding Navigation controller from the menu bar.